# selenium insert text to microsoft word frame

Tags: python, selenium, iframe, textbox

I'm using selenium with python.
I got some text box the site that looks like word document and I'm trying to insert text into it.
but I didn't figure it out, how to put the text in there.

I tried this code:

driver.find_element_by_xpath("//[@id='description_heb___Frame']").send_keys("xxxx")

but nothing happened.
I'm adding screenshot of the text box with the html code

[image]

Comment: Please read why a [screenshot of HTML or code or error is a bad idea](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors). Consider updating the Question with formatted text based relevant HTML, code trials and error stack trace.

Answer (score 1):

First switch to the frame:

```
driver.switch_to.frame(driver.find_element_by_id('description_heb___Frame'))
driver.find_element_by_id('description_heb').send_keys('random text');
```

when you are done with the frame:

```
driver.switch_to.default_content()
```

Comment: got:
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"id","selector":"description_heb"}

Comment: any idea?
I think I found more inner frame

Comment: @user8446864 Rather adding as comments, edit the main question with the additional information for a proper analysis.